# App Service node.js app port setting not taking

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-instances

Hi I am not able to set App Service container PORT. You can see that the Linux container cant find the 5000 PORT env setting. This is a code deployed via VScode and not git actions or container.

You can see the app starts and shows the server port used. But it gets killed later on because Azure service cant ping the app (because its deploying in wrong port 8080).The error I am getting when it fails is as follows.

This article addresses this issue close enough but i have tried everything mentioned there.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#your-container-must-respond-to-an-http-pingapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

Thanks

```
/home/LogFiles/2022_01_26_lw0sdlwk00018U_docker.log  (https://nodeAPP.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_01_26_lw0sdlwk00018U_docker.log)
2022-01-26T03:28:53.943Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1692.0405881 sec
2022-01-26T03:29:15.365Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1713.4632047 sec
2022-01-26T03:29:30.540Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1728.6378004 sec
2022-01-26T03:29:47.648Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1745.7457782 sec
2022-01-26T03:30:04.293Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1762.3906187 sec
2022-01-26T03:30:22.075Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1780.1730924 sec
2022-01-26T03:30:37.241Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0. Elapsed time = 1795.3388017 sec
2022-01-26T03:30:42.309Z ERROR - Container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0 for site nodeAPP did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 1800.4068778 sec
2022-01-26T03:30:42.328Z ERROR - Container nodeAPP_0_8c9f94c0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-01-26T03:30:42.377Z INFO  - Stopping site nodeAPP because it failed during startup.
```

Here is the code of the app.

```
const port = process.env.PORT | 3000

// Require the framework and instantiate it
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

// Declare a route
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
    return { hello: 'world' }
})


fastify.get('/ping', async (request, reply) => {
    return { pong: 'it worked!' }
})

// Run the server!
const start = async () => {
    try {
        await fastify.listen(port)
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    } catch (err) {
        fastify.log.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
start()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change the listening port for your NodeJS app running on a Linux App Service plan, create and set `PORT` application setting to your desired port. App Service will always listen on port 8080 on startup but will redirect to your specified port as long as it successfully pings.

Comment: unfortunately that is not what i'm experiencing as well. Using Node 14, Linux App service setting, I'm seeing docker initiate with port 2551. even though I have set the port in configuration to 8080. matter of fact, it does not run the startup command i have specified as well.